# How to get particular updated of new added filed value in MYSQL CI?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, user-tracking

I am working on the CI in this project i need to implement user activity tracking for logged in user like if any user see any records i can save that to the database and if any record is updated then i need show get only that particular updated filed value and show in the log table like this user 'xyz' has updated the phone number from '123456' to '546789'. like this if any recorded is updated, added, deleted, or viewed then i want to able to track that, i hope that make sense.
Any help is appreciated....

Comment: Well you can either write php for it or look into mysql triggers. Good luck!

Comment: @jedifans  can you help me with this more and how can i apply it in CI.

Comment: I'm sorry, stack overflow isn't a code writing service. Give it a go and post a question with the specific code you are having trouble with.

Comment: I am using this link code as suggested by Isaak Mogetutu => https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codeigniter-kenya/ah3d5Clyqcc

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a column in your table which will store the activity. when your required event is triggered.e.g.Updating Employee No. 1 to 100 will Store Activity as an Update and you can add one more column to store the ID of the updated Entry. hope this helps.